# Typescript readonly typed class doesn't collide with regular typescript class if the structure is the same

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

I know typescript has a structural typing mechanism. I would expect however, that if you have a class like this:

```
class Country {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

and one defined like this:

```
class ReadonlyCountry {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly name: string;     
}
```

that the typing system would show collisions if you return an object with the `ReadonlyCountry` type in a function that has as return type `Country`. It appears this is not the case as in the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Country%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ReadonlyCountry%20%3D%20Readonly%3CCountry%3E%3B%0A%0Afunction%20select(value%3A%20string)%3A%20ReadonlyCountry%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20country%20%3D%20new%20Country()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20country.id%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20country.name%20%3D%20%22name%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bcountry%5D%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20select2(value%3A%20string)%3A%20Country%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20select(value)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A) example shown below.

```js
class Country {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

class ReadonlyCountry {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly name: string;    
}

function select(value: string): ReadonlyCountry[] {
    let country = new Country();
    country.id = "1";
    country.name = "name";
    return [country]; 
}

function select2(value: string): Country[] {
    // the type of the return here will be ReadonlyCountry[]
    // the type of the function return here is Country[]
    // why doesn't this collide?
    return select(value);
}
```

So my question is, how can I make sure that a type which has readonly properties and a type which does not have readonly types, and which are structurally the same, show type errors when mixed?
Am I missing something stupid here and is it just the structural typing which causes this to happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a structural typing that cause your problems. I think you should reconsider the structure of your classes and try avoid those with identical structure that must be treated differently.

As a side note. Instead of creating the read-only versions of the same classes (thus duplicating your code and introducing maintenance headache) why not to use mapped types ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)), and specifically `Readonly` one already predefined for you:

```
function select(value: string): Readonly<Country>[]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about the Readonly mapped type and intend to use it. 
This however is kind of a problem to me. I'm using Redux and want to make the state coming from my store readonly. This means having an object that looks the same without reaonly properties (the ones that go into my store) and the reaonly variant (the one that comes out of my store). I'm afraid that it will be impossible however....

Comment: I think you should go with Readonly, and if you want - ensure readonly at runtime also by freezing them immediately after receiving them from store (http://www.2ality.com/2013/08/protecting-objects.html).

Comment: Readonly fixes my problem if I define it everywhere. But if somebody forgets to define it properly, I would like typescript to pick it up. If it doesn't do it (like above in my example) I'm sure developers will f** it up somewhere.
I already use some freezing library to have runtime checks but I would like to have it at compile time.